# Binary search in python

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I'm stuck on this little bit of code. I need to read in a users input for the charge number and compare it to the account numbers array. then tell the user if the number is valid or not. I also have to do this using a binary search algorithm. Right now when I run the program I'm able to enter a charge number, but nothing happens after that. not sure of what I missed, or what i need to add/ change.

Thank you!

```
def main():

    accountNumbers = [5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 8080152, 4562555, 5552012, 5050552, 7825877, 1250255, 1005231, 6545321, 3852085, 7576651, 7881200,  4581002]
    accountNumbers.sort()
    chargeNumber = int(input('Please enter a charge number: '))
    binary_search(accountNumbers, chargeNumber)

def binary_search(accountNumbers, chargeNumber):

    first = 0
    last = len(accountNumbers) - 1
    found = 0
    while first <= last and found == 0:
        placeHolder = (first + last) // 2

        if accountNumbers[placeHolder] == chargeNumber:
            found = 1          
        else:
            if  chargeNumber < accountNumbers[placeHolder]:
                first = placeHolder + 1

            else:
                last = placeHolder - 1
    if  found == 1:  
        print('Charge account number', chargeNumber, 'was in the system.')
    else:
        print('Charge account number', chargeNumber, 'was not in the system.')        

main()
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use python's built-in [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) methods?

Comment: The problem might lie in you have an expression and not an assignment... `found == 1` and `first == placeHolder + 1` and `last == placeHolder - 1`

Comment: I think you have your `first = ...` and `last = ...` statements switched too. If `chargedNumber` is less than the pivot value (is that what it's called in binary searches?), then you want to look at everything *before* the pivot, and vice versa

Comment: @cricket_007 i changed those, but then I get an incorrect value retuned also I'm not familiar with the method..

Comment: You could look at "Searching Sorted Lists" on that page.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo... instead of using `=` you have used `==` for assignment operator. Change

```
first == placeHolder + 1
```

To

```
first = placeHolder + 1
```

Similarly, in the `else` clause "assignment"

Comment: Thank you. Changed those, but now no matter what I enter I receive the same value, even if an incorrect value is entered

Comment: See @KevinOrr's explanantion - the pivot test also needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the typos that Dinesh mentioned, there are a few more problems.

`found == 1` is another such typo. It should be `found = 1`.

You're looking at the wrong half of the remaining list. If `chargeNumber` is less than the current pivot value, then you should be looking at the *first* half of the list (i.e. `last = placeHolder - 1`). Switching the `first =` and `last =` statements should fix that, or changing `<` to `>`.

When you check for `found` at the end, you're printing the wrong messages. Again, switching the two `print` calls should fix that. Also, `if found:` should be sufficient (instead of `if found == 1`), since `bool(1) == True`.

Also, I would recommend is python's `bool` types. It'll be fine if you use an `int`, since `bool()` is called on any non-`bool` types when one is needed, but it better communicates your intent to use `found` as a boolean type.